# TabBar disappearing on dismiss of a modal

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am integrating a 3rd party chat app [slaask](https://slaask.com/) into my iOS App with tab bar. When the Chat tab button is clicked the Chat modal window is shown.

The below code automatically presents a modal as shown in the below image

Steps followed:

1. Embedded Slaask Binary
2. Added code to AppDelegate

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   // Configuring Slaask chat
   let config      = SLAASKConfig.init(slaaskToken: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
   let manager     = SLAASKManager.sharedInstance
   manager.config  = config
   }
   ```
3. Added the below method in the view controller

   ```
   import UIKit
   import slaask

   class ChatVC: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           SLAASKManager.sharedInstance.show()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       }
   }
   ```

[image]

When Chat modal is dismissed, the tabBarController is disappearing along with it. Could some one please suggest how I can resolve this ?

Comment: are you adding SLAASKManager to tab bar controller?

Comment: I edited my question with the code that I added into AppDelegate.swift file

Comment: @surabh Jain, No, I am adding it to ViewController

Comment: please add it on the third tab of the tab bar controller

Comment: @SaurabhJain, Nope, It doesn't work